# Excel Help! 2 worksheets and multiple formulas for comparing data

Tags: excel, compare, formulas

I have worksheet 1 that I will need to upload to a database. I have worksheet 2 that has possible updated information for worksheet 1. I want to compare what is on worksheet 1 with worksheet 2 and if there are any differences update worksheet 1 with the info in worksheet 2 and change Column a in that row to "Update".

Example
I have an ID number in B2 in worksheet 1. I want to see if it matches an ID number in worksheet 2 anywhere in column B. If it does I want it to check the address in worksheet 1 S2 and compare it to the same id address in worksheet 2 which is in column S. If they match do nothing, if they are different update worksheet 1 (S2) with the address in worksheet 2 and change worksheet A2 to "Update".

now this is just the first step but if someone can help me with this i might be able to figure out the rest.

I will then need to check other columns to make sure they match and if not do the same stuff mention above. If someone could show me how to combine multiple checks into the same formula that would be great. For example check the address and County name (worksheet 1 x2, worksheet 2 x:x) and check the age (worksheet 1 af2, worksheet 2 af:af)

I have been working on this for a week now and i have made no progress. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: create a third worksheet. Copy the unique id column from ws1 into ws3. Write an `IF(ISERROR(match(A1,ws2![ID COLUMN],0),ws1!A1,vlookup(A1,ws2!$A:A,1,0))` adjust ranges and absolute references and drag over. You'll have a sheet with all the updates ready to lead. A1 assumes the first id in A1

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for the reply. I tried for a couple days to get your formula to work but i am having no success. I named my worksheet 1, WS1, Worksheet 2, WS2, and the new worksheet, formula. Each time i get you've enterted too many arguments for this function. Can you provide any help? This is what i have entered =if(iserror(match(A2,'WS2'!B:B,0),'WS1'!B2,vlookup(Formula!A2,'WS2'!B:B,1,0))